# Time out error while waiting to lock object

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, parallel-processing

My procedure fails at times, and further investigation reveals that it is always the same error:

> ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P02U
>   ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object 
>   ORA-06512: at "USP_ALGO_REPORT", line 645

I've tried several things (don't know if they are helpful or not), for instance, bringing down from `parallel(16)` to `parallel(8)` for all my select statements inside the procedure, changing the timings when the procedure is scheduled to run etc.

Please let me know If I can provide further information that can help understand the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: How about removing *parallel* completely?

Comment: Show us the statement at line 645. Is it a query or `INSERT`?

Comment: I can try that. But the whole purpose of fast processing will be defeated. Do you think it really could be because of parallelism?

Comment: You should first investigate which object failed to be locked - do you use some functions, packages etc. in your statement? And re-thing, we know **noting about your procedure** except it is called `USP_ALGO_REPORT`, **how could we assist you**?

Comment: How many nodes (CPUs) does your computer have?

Comment: RAISE; -- is what is present on line 645

Answer (score 0):

> My procedure fails at times

Check error ORA-06512 in [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e4100.htm).

Fix the problem causing the exception or write an exception handler for this condition on line 645.

Like:

```
    if something 
       return 1
```

Comment: @APC No, I suggest adding at least some processing to its string. There's also black and white written what is the error. And I kind of clearly answered :(
Maybe not written in English, because with it isn't good enough. It sounds better in Russian in my head. :)
f a person understands at least a little in the SQL, then he must understand my answer.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you wanted to solve the parallel query problem. So you are suggesting the OP should be happy just to live with it?

Comment: @APC I believe that everything is good with parallelism. If sometimes performed. He told "My procedure fails at times".

Comment: The specific error is ORA-12801, which is a problem with parallel query. You are suggesting they handle the general PL/SQL error ORA-06512, which basically means *something went wrong in the procedure, look at the callstack to see the specific problem we need to fix". Now, I think the OP wants us to help them fix the ORA-12801 issue but they haven't provided enough detail for us to do that. But maybe they just want a generic error handler, in which case I'm sure they'll accept your answer.

Comment: My apologies guys! I am new to sql and pl/sql. I am sure I have missed a lot of required details for you all to figure out what's going on.

Comment: And correct it runs fine except few times when it fails and gives the errors that i mentioned above. My apologies again, I will write again with what the procedure does so that there is a better understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after performing DML statements, try to commit.

```
 timeout occurred while waiting to lock object
```

at cases,this resolves the timeout issue.

committing the session releases the locking object can can be used for next command....